# overflow error 6 when handling certain files in folder

Tags: excel, vba, exif, windows-scripting

I wanted to get a list in excel of all my photos, with some exif data (date taken, camera make and model).

I ran it against my folder of about 3000 files, and it went perfectly for 1796 of them.

I commented out the "on error resume next" to see what was going on.

I got an error 6 overflow on this line:

```
objExif.Load objFile.Path
```

If I move the already processed pictures out of the folder, The macro errors out right away when examining the remaining.
If I run the macro against the already processed pictures in a new folder, no errors are thrown.

This leads to the conclusion that there is something different about both sets of picture, but nothing that I can see.
Both sets are digital photos, unedited, with valid exif data.

I hope someone can help me?

Code:

```
Private objFSO As Object, objTopFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Private i As Long
Private objExif As New ExifReader

Sub GetFiles()

    On Error Resume Next

    i = 2
    Worksheets("Filelist").Range("A2:G5000").Value = ""
    Worksheets("Paths").Range("A2:A5000").Value = ""
    Worksheets("Data").Range("E15:E5000").Value = ""

    If Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C2").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B3").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B3").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C3").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B4").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B4").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C4").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B5").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B5").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C5").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C6").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C7").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B8").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B8").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C8").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B9").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B9").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C9").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C10").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B11").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B11").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C11").Value)

    Sheets("Filelist").Range("G1:G10000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Data").Range("E15"), Unique:=True
    Sheets("Filelist").Range("B2").Select
End Sub

Sub Filelist(TopFolder As String, includesub As String)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(TopFolder)
    If includesub = "yes" Then
        Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)
    Else
        Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, False)
    End If
End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "jpg" Or Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "JPG" Then
            objExif.Load objFile.Path
            txtDate = objExif.Tag(DateTimeOriginal)
            txtmake = objExif.Tag(Make)
            txtmodel = objExif.Tag(Model)
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Path
            Worksheets("Paths").Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Path
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 2) = objFile.Name
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 3) = txtDate
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 4) = txtmake
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 5) = txtmodel
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 7) = Left(txtDate, 4)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next objFile

    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How large are the files?

Comment: ranging from 500 - 9900 kB

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it after some more digging around.

I moved the "on error" statement to a different sub (the one which actually does all the work), so that on error, the next file is loaded, instead of skipping the sub entirely.

All files except for one were now processed.

That one file turned out to be corrupted.

```
Private objFSO As Object, objTopFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Private i As Long
Private objExif As New ExifReader

Sub GetFiles()
    i = 2
    Worksheets("Filelist").Range("A2:G5000").Value = ""
    Worksheets("Paths").Range("A2:A5000").Value = ""
    Worksheets("Data").Range("E15:E5000").Value = ""

    If Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C2").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B3").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B3").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C3").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B4").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B4").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C4").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B5").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B5").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C5").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C6").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C7").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B8").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B8").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C8").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B9").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B9").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C9").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C10").Value)
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B11").Value <> "" Then Call Filelist(Sheets("Data").Range("B11").Value, Sheets("Data").Range("C11").Value)

    Sheets("Filelist").Range("G1:G10000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Data").Range("E15"), Unique:=True
    Sheets("Filelist").Range("B2").Select
End Sub

Sub Filelist(TopFolder As String, includesub As String)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(TopFolder)
    If includesub = "yes" Then
        Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)
    Else
        Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, False)
    End If
End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "jpg" Or Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "JPG" Then
            objExif.Load objFile.Path
            txtDate = objExif.Tag(DateTimeOriginal)
            txtmake = objExif.Tag(Make)
            txtmodel = objExif.Tag(Model)
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Path
            Worksheets("Paths").Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Path
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 2) = objFile.Name
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 3) = txtDate
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 4) = txtmake
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 5) = txtmodel
            Worksheets("Filelist").Cells(i, 7) = Left(txtDate, 4)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next objFile

    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try providing more detailed/well-written answer. Your question seems interesting to me. A good answer can help other users as well.

Comment: To clarify: my fault was that in the original code, I place my "on error resume next" statement in the main sub. When an error was encountered (a corrupt file in this case), the main sub would resume to the next sub, ending any further file processing. I now placed the error handler in the sub which actually processses the files, so that when an error is encountered, the next file is tried.